openstack sdk unable to get the running vms on specific compute
I'm trying to get list of vms that are running on some specific hypervisor from openstack api, so here python request.
import openstack

openstack.enable_logging(debug=True)
conn = openstack.connect(cloud='mycloud')

print(conn.list_servers(filters={"host": "compute-001"}))

my output is an empty list : []
Thanks in advance
Tried with another method :
conn.compute.find_hypervisor("compute-001", details=True)


Nothing about the running vms, but state of compute is printed
Expected behavior :
list of vms
